# 'Pricing tier' details of Azure SQL databases - powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to get pricing tier details of Azure SQL databases  through powershell ? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the rest api from powershell to get the pricing details:
[new-azure-billing-apis-available](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-azure-billing-apis-available)

For the pricing details you can call the ratecard api: [Get price and metadata information for resources used in an Azure subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the Azure new Rate Card API to fetch the pricing information about your resource. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview

It is tedious to read the whole article, but you can reference this sample post for your task [How to calculate Azure SQL databases price by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com//How-to-calculate-Azure-SQL-d0acbce8)

Below is code snippet

```
$Ret = Invoke-AzureRestGetAPI -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionid/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&`$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-$OfferDurableId' and Currency eq '$Currency' and Locale eq '$Locale' and RegionInfo eq '$RegionInfo'" 

$Sum = 0 
$Ret.Meters | ForEach-Object { 
    If ($_.MeterSubCategory -eq "SQL Database") { 
        $Sum += $_.MeterRates.0 
        Write-Host ($_ | ConvertTo-Json -depth 4) 
        Write-Host "" 
    } 
}
```